# What's wrong with this VB.net syntax to pass query string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

```
this code will not pass the query string to default3.aspx on Image Button ..
```

I think there is some error in my syntax, please help me to sort out the error.. in code below :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "window.showModalDialog('Default3.aspx?id='" + Label4.Text + ",'','dialogHeight: 400px; dialogWidth: 370px;');return false;")
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify code as below

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles   Me.Load
      ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "window.showModalDialog('Default3.aspx?id=" + Label4.Text + "','','dialogHeight: 400px; dialogWidth: 370px;');return false;");
End Sub
```

Hope this will help you...